# Why can html.twig files be placed outside the templates folder?

Tags: theming, 9

In [Drupal theme folder structure](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/drupal-theme-folder-structure), there is written:

> Templates provide HTML markup and some presentation logic. Contrary to Drupal 7, in Drupal 8 template files (*.html.twig files) must be stored in the 'templates' subfolder.

In my theme, I have a *styleguide* folder at the root. Drupal 9 finds template files, such as *mytheme/styleguide/components/10-atoms/form/input.html.twig*, in this folder.

Drupal 9 will use this input.html.twig file despite it's not in the mytheme/templates folder.

Comment: Yes, normally Drupal looks for Twig files in the templates subfolder, but there are several ways to change that. For example in a hook_theme or in an alternative Twig file loader like https://www.drupal.org/project/components

Comment: I just don't understand why Drupal find suggestion ouside the templates folder in the theme.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about mytheme, which base theme, content of the info file or other details that might be important. Do you have any modules installed that might be related?

Comment: With a fresh installation, my twig template isn't in the templates folder & it's working.
But I'm using a styleguide folder in the theme & I don't want Drupal to use it on his own.
I just want it to use those in the (bartikssen/)templates folder.

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * page--front.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   x page.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/bartikssen/page.html.twig' -->

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found a solution, I just need to add in my settings.php the "styleguide" folder in the ignore directories

```
$settings['file_scan_ignore_directories'] = [
  'node_modules',
  'bower_components',
  'styleguide'
];
```